# How to fix Cannot assign value of type 'DataClass' to type '[DataClass]’ Error using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am Implementing `JSON` data with `Codable`. Here, I can’t able to assign let data: DataClass values into array. I am getting error `"Cannot assign value of type 'DataClass' to type '[DataClass]’`. How to fix this?

**My JSON Codable**

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let agid, teamid, genname, dataDescription: String
    let schools: [School]
    let games, reminder: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case agid, teamid, genname
        case dataDescription = "description"
        case schools, games, reminder
    }
}

// MARK: - School
struct School: Codable {
    let name, team: String
}
```

**My JSON Load Code**

```
func loadJSON(){
    let urlPath = ""
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil && error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self,  from: data!)
            let status = decoder.status
            if status == true {
                self.schoolsData = decoder.data.schools
                self.filteredSec = decoder.data // Getting Error Here
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: How is your `filteredSec` declared? I guess it is an Array of `DataClass`, if so, why it is an Array?

Comment: You have not answered my question, why it is an Array?

Comment: `let decoder` is a misleading variable name - it's not a decoder, it's the result of running a decoder. Storing some of your decoded structure (`self.schoolsData = decoder.data.schools`) **and** storing it's parent structure (`self.filteredSec = decoder.data`) is redundant.

Comment: Your `data` in `Welcome` is not an Array. You never get multiple `DataClass` from your API. Why Array?

Comment: Your API returns only one `DataClass`, please explain why `filteredSec` is an Array?

Comment: I said already your API returns only one `DataClass`, only one `agid`, only one `teamid`, only one `genname`, why Array?

Comment: @OOPer ohh man do you know how to get that values?

Comment: Perhaps we should start by giving `DataClass` a better name? What does it represent? A team? And you need to have the concept of multiple teams? If so, then that is what your API should return. If instead you intend to present the data for a single team in multiple ways, then you only need one copy of that data.

Comment: @Chris how to use that value in another function.

Comment: You may need to find another API or need to re-structure your app.

Comment: Please expand your explanation in simple English to help us help you. e.g. "My API returns a description of a team. I want to display that data in a tableView cell. When that cell is tapped, I want to show more details in another view".